# Unable to instantiate activity exception on a Intel device

Tags: java, android, gradle, x86, arm

I try to run a project on Android Acer device with Intel CPU but there is an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.xxx.xxxx/com.xx.xxx.xxxx.GameActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.xx.xxx.xxxx.GameActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xx.xxx.xxxx-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.xx.xxx.xxxx-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
```

On Arm devices, projects work fine. I also have GameActivity in my AndroidManifest.xml. It seemed that the application can't find java classes. What can be wrong? Are there some issues with intel devices?

Here is my build.gradle

```
sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
            }
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true

            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        res.srcDir "res"
        jniLibs.srcDir "libs"
        assets.srcDir "assets"
        manifest.srcFile "AndroidManifest.xml"
        java.srcDir "src"
        aidl.srcDirs "src"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3'

    implementation files('SwrveSDK/libs/SwrveSDK.jar')
    implementation files('SwrveSDKCommon/libs/SwrveSDKCommon.jar')
    implementation files('SwrveConversationSDK/libs/SwrveConversationSDK.jar')

    implementation (project(':downloader_library'))
    implementation (project(':zip_file'))

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:18.0.1'
}
```

Comment: can you verify using apk analyser if the binaries for x86 are present. If not show us you build.gradle configuration

Comment: @NIKHILMAURYA but the trouble is not in binaries, it can't find java activity which is not in binaries *.so files